# codeigniter: how do I use echo on the value of the array and use it on chart javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

i have a array like this

```
array(3) { 
          [14]=> float(0.50547994217896) 
          [16]=> float(0.4579451429427) 
          [17]=> float(0.6121066479873) 
         }
```

and a javascript

```
data : [
         <?php echo ......... ;?>, // value from index [14]
         <?php echo ......... ;?>, // value from index [16]
         <?php echo ......... ;?>  // value from index [17]
       ]
```

how to fill array values into javascript `data : [....]` and then bring up the array values using `echo` inside?

> the array is **dinamically**, so array keys dan values can changed anytime

Comment: `json_encode()` is your friend

Comment: how its implementation for my case? because I plan to use it to change the array value into a chart @Rizier123

Comment: Just do it like this: `var yourJSVariable = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using inline javascript rather than separate file of .js than you can simply echo again variables like this (in my case array have 0,1,2 respective values) in your case its 14,16,17

```
$data=array(0.50547994217896,0.4579451429427, 0.6121066479873) ;
data:[
    <?php 
       for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++)
       {
           echo $data[$i];
       }
    ?>
]
```

now changed the logic from simple to looped data. so you can loop through in number of counts in an array
regards

Comment: thanks for the reply . but what if my array is dynamic? array index can be changed anytime @imranqasim